# Command binding to a GridView of buttons

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, commandbinding

I have a `GridView` which is bound to a List of `Objects X` in the `ViewModel`, I want to Command bind to each button, so that in when I click the button i get info from the selected X object and view it somewhere else.

Simply as that. I can't seem to find a reference to the selected GridView item that's bound to that particular button from the `ViewModel` codeBehind.

Answer (score 0):

There is no binding path that you could 'resolve' from the Button down to the selected `GridView` item.

However if you check the `SelectedItem` property (which should be bound to a property on the viewmodel as well) from your command event handler you will have the reference to the item you are clicking the button in.